# How to iterate an object, that has sub arrays or objects with same property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here, how do I get sum of all ages? How do I iterate all age properties of different objects ?

This is my solution. I know it's not efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

```js
const family = {

  name: "Jon",
  age: 100,
  kids: [{
      name: "Julia",
      age: 70,
      kids: [{
        name: "Json",
        age: 50
      }, {
        name: "Jasper",
        age: 30
      }]
    },
    {
      name: "June",
      age: 60,
      kids: [{
        name: "Jane",
        age: 20
      }]
    }
  ]
}


let total = 0
total = family.age


function AddAges(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj.kids)) {
    obj.kids.forEach(kid => {
      total = total + kid.age
      AddAges(kid)
    })
  }
}

AddAges(family)
console.log(total)
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: This question is too broad. You should update your question with the code you've written (as a [mcve]) to solve your problem. Please read the article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani  added my code.

Comment: @Varunr Okay cool

Answer (score 3):

You could take an object's `age` and `kids` by a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and reduce the `kids` array by calling the function again for each `kid`.

If the object does not include a property `kids`, or if the value is `undefined`, then it takes an array as [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values).

```js
function getSum({ age, kids = [] }) {
    return kids.reduce((s, kid) => s + getSum(kid), age);
}

const family = { name: "Jon", age: 100, kids: [{ name: "Julia", age: 70, kids: [{ name: "Json", age: 50 }, { name: "Jasper", age: 30 }] }, { name: "June", age: 60, kids: [{ name: "Jane", age: 20 }] }] };

console.log(getSum(family));
```